# What are the risks to update 18.04.5 kernel (5.4.0-74) to the latest 5.4.125 to match the PREEMP_RT patch?

Tags: 18.04, kernel, compiling, realtime

Good day everyone!

I see that uname -r returns 5.4.0-74 in my 18.04.5

I don't see any version like this at kernel.org.
Why the dash?
I hear that Ubuntu makes changes to their kernel.
This suggests going to get source on kernel.org and building would break things?

I want to install the PREEMPT-RT patch and change only this setting to avoid breaking things. I assume the patch has to be the same version as the kernel version?

Not sure how this kernel choice should be made.

I see at kernel.org that 5.4.125 is latest 5.4 long-term support.
is this also stable?

Totally ignorant here so any advice would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu

Comment: great link but ... will it be risky? ... apt upgrade does not offer this newer kernel.

Comment: Apt offers only kernels that somebody has packaged and tested. Ubuntu offers a packaged low-latency kernel (see [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/)), but not a realtime kernel ([reasons](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel)).

Comment: I see now that the dash represents patches or bug fix's.

Comment: Also I have seen one person say that you should get the latest PREEMPT_RT patch as long as the 1st two numbers match ... but now I see many who say the kernel version (ie: 5.4.0) must match the PREMPT_RT version... the later seems to be the consensus.

Comment: @user535733 ... I see that my 18.04.5 has an option for the PREEMPT_RT low latency which by default is not selected ... I should be able to rebuild with this setting and get the same thing as Ubuntu Studio ??

Comment: What I don't understand is that default 18.04.5 kernel is labeled 5.4.0-74 ... but there is no version of that number at kernel.ubuntu.com ? How do I get the exact source I want if I need to stay at my kernel version and just change one setting?

Comment: Try https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic-signed.git/log/?h=hwe-5.4

Comment: Thanks but I am still confused ... (uname -r) returns 5.4.0-74 ... none of the number on your link match.

Comment: Also when I ... apt source linux-image-&(uname -r) ... when I compile and reboot uname -r returns 5.4.114 ?? ... I am not getting the same kernel source on my PC that I want to keep.